# Configure azure diagnostics on existing web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

I have an existing App which has logging enabled on Log4net , which runs on VS 2012.
The logs are sent on a database table, I woiuld like to move it to use azure tables.
I have added the following lines in web.config as well as downloaded the Azure SDK.

`<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>`
What else do I need to do to start logging using azure tables ?
For a start is there a way I can run the website on local and configure things to be logged on azure table on the storage emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add  to the web.config of your web app.  To enable logging to an Azure Storage Table, go to the **configure** page of your web app in the Azure Management portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com.  (The preview portal currently doesn't support this).

In the application diagnostics section, set **application logging (table storage)** to **ON**, specify your logging level, and then click the manage table storage button to specify the storage account and table name you want to write logs to.  Then click the **SAVE** button at the bottom of the page and you're done.

[image]

Comment: The application is not deployed yet, I want to view it in the storage emulator first

Comment: I wouldn't recommend taking a dependency on the storage emulator for local trace logging. You're going to have to add dependencies to your project to get it to work.  For example, go look at a WebRole and you will see all the pieces required.  You will need the Azure Storage package and there is a diagnostics plugin you will need as well.  There may be some code that needs to be added to your solution also to get it to work - not sure.  I've not tried this approach.  Instead, I would stick with traditional approaches for local logging like WebPageTraceListener and trace.axd.

Comment: I actually have an existing web app that uses log4net, I need to implement logging using azure tables. I looked at http://zacg.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/azure-log4net-appender/
but my app is not launching , the azure table gets created though